# pandas - merge on sliced table gives bigger result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got to Dataframes (~1000 rows each) with overlapping unicode indexing which I want to merge based on the index.

The weird part is I'm getting fewer results when merging the whole dataframes than I do when I merge slices of them.

```
In [5]: len(pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True))
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: len(pd.merge(df1[:100],df2[:100],left_index=True,right_index=True))
Out[6]: 67
```

Does anyone have an explanation? can you think of a "pandas solution" (as opposed to going over the indexes with a for loop)?

Comment: I think it is because parameter `how is default ‘inner’` [see](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?